# Google Sheets - Filter for all open (status) tasks with category and task description into a summary tab

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

Stuck on this :
I want to filter a summary in a new tab to show all "open" tasks with their category and include task description. If there a formula or query for this.
I included a screenshot of the data - sorry I can't share its work document.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY(A2:O; "where O = 'Open'"; 1)
```

Comment: As a brief clarification to this formula [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) basically filters from your range ```A2:O``` only taking those rows where column ```O```'s value is ```Open``` (the condition). The last parameter is to include 1 row in this range of headers (as your range starts in ```A2``` this would be row 2) which are where your ```Category``` title, ```Works description``` and so on are.

Comment: OH thank you so much - I will give this a go.  Truly appreciate you responding.